# Google Play Store Build Errors: Overcoming Size Limitations for Android App Bundles (AAB) (2.000mb error)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, android-app-bundle

When attempting to upload my game to the Google Play Store via the "Google > Build Android App Bundle" option with the "Separate Base APK & Asset Packs" enabled, I encountered the following error: "One or more of your multiple automatically generated APKs exceeds 2,000 MB. Reduce the size of your components to create multiple APKs in a smaller size." [View Error İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qwJl.jpg)

Additionally, when building my game from the build settings with the AAB build and "Split Application Binary" option enabled, I faced another error: "The total download size of the initially installed Asset Packs in this App Bundle is 1256622019. The merge size of the initially installed Asset Packs can be up to 1074000000." [View Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAbte.jpg)
I've attempted both approaches, and unfortunately, both have resulted in errors.